# Set_my_commands error aiogram asyncio python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiogram

I am working on a bot in aiogram 3, and when I try to use the built-in set_my_commands command, the bot launch is interrupted with the following errors:

```
raise validation_error
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for BotCommand
description
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0424A148>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 711, in call_soon
  File "D:\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 504, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Here are code snippets that **roughly reflect the essence** of what is written in the project (the whole project is too big to cite) :

**File commands.py with the location project.core.utils.commands**

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.types import BotCommand, BotCommandScopeDefault

async def set_commands(bot: Bot):
    commands = [BotCommand(command='start', descriptions='Begin work')]
    await bot.set_my_commands(commands, BotCommandScopeDefault())
```

**File basic.py with the location core.handlers.basic.py**

```
from aiogram.types import Message

async def get_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f'Hi {message.from_user.first_name}. Welcome!')
```

**File main.py with the location project.main.py**

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from core.handlers.basic import get_start
import asyncio
from core.settings import settings
from aiogram.filters import Command
from core.utils.commands import set_commands

async def start_bot(bot: Bot):
    print('Bot started!')
    await set_commands(bot)

async def stop_bot(bot: Bot):
    print('Bot stopped!')

async def start():
    bot = Bot(token=settings.bots.bot_token, parse_mode='HTML')
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.startup.register(start_bot)
    dp.shutdown.register(stop_bot)
    dp.message.register(get_start, Command(commands=['start']))

    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

I don't think this code is important in my error, we are specifically interested in set_my_commands.

---

**Some useful information about the error:**

- This error occurs only when I declare `await set_commands(bot)` in the `start_bot` function. Without it, the bot runs perfectly and there are no warnings and errors.
- The last fragment of the error I have given, starting with `Exception ignored in:` and ending with `RuntimeError:` is duplicated 10 times in the terminal.
- I wrote the code based on the video tutorial, the author of the video has a similar code that does not cause any errors. However, I have newer versions of the libraries.
- Here are the versions of the libraries used:

`Python 3.8`
`aiogram 3.0.0.b7`
`asyncio 3.4.3`
`aiohttp 3.8.4`
`Windows 10`

---

Please do not leave links to similar questions unrelated to aiogram, give a concrete example of a solution to my problem, or describe what exactly the error is.

---

**So a list of what I was looking for and tried:**

- I was looking for a solution to this problem on the Internet, but I only saw solutions related to aiohttp and FastApi.
- I tried adding `await async io.sleep(0.1)` after the `finally:` block.
- I replaced `asyncio.run(start())` with various other "similar" versions written on websites.
- I also tried a lot of other "questionable" tips I found.
- I know that you can add commands to telegram via BotFather, but I'm not satisfied with this option, because you can't select `BotCommandScope` there.
- I was checking my code against the video I used to write it. I have not found any constructive differences other than the version of the libraries.

---

All of the above options did not affect the performance of the code. I'm probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your commands.py when you describe commands in list, your BotCommand's argument 'descriptions' should look like 'description' (without 's' letter at the end)

Your log:
1 validation error for BotCommand
**description
field required** (type=value_error.missing)

I think that is the reason of error.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice this annoying typo. This solved the problem.